# How to implement Viber Chatbot when since public is disabled

Tags: node.js, chatbot, viber

We have developed a Whatsapp chatbot for one of our clients. He appreciated and wanted us to do the same with Viber. I searched the documentation but I can't seem to do the tests. Is there a way to create a chatbot using our own number or others.
I noticed that public accounts have been disabled recently.

Comment: Thi slink was very helphfull for me.https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/#get-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find information about bot creation in [Viber official documentation](https://developers.viber.com/docs/api/rest-bot-api/).